# Highcharts JS: Gap between X-Axis labels is too thin

Tags: javascript, css, datetime, types, highcharts

The gap between the labels in the X-Axis is to small, when i scale the window size and more labels can be shown. The Highcharts engine calculates the gap and set at different break points a gap of zero. The labels touching each other and for this problem i need a solution.

> I've testing it and the rotation of 90 degrees is not the problem.

```
type: 'datetime',
labels: {
    rotation: -90
}
```

**LIVE ON:** [jsfiddle.net/k5ckfh76/](http://jsfiddle.net/k5ckfh76/)

Comment: you should use tickInterval to avoid xAxis label's overlapping when larger
                    points are there. Also you can use staggerLine property to maintain alternate order of labels to avoid collapsing among them.

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: Ok, jsFiddle is now online.

Answer (score 1):

```
labels: {
    style: {
        color: 'blue'
    },
    rotation: 90,
    staggerLines: 2
}
```

Comment: otherwise try this  labels: {step: 2}

Comment: In your first solution, the labels are displayed alternately up and down. And step:2 is also not the way I would like to.

Comment: I like to set the minWidth for the gap between the labels.

Comment: But that's just a function of how much space there is, and how many labels you're trying to put there...

Comment: There will automatically appear to many labels at different settings, that the labels touching each other.

Comment: can you give snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Using categories is setting type of axis to `category`, but then you are setting type of axis to `datetime` - it cannot be both. When using time it is recommended to use `datetime`, not `category`.

When using `datetime` axis type it is possible to set `tickPixelInterval` - to prevent labels from getting too close to each other.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k5ckfh76/1/

[API reference for tickPixelInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPixelInterval)

Comment: It is possible to display the first and last date ?

Comment: Setting to true: [startOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.startOnTick), [endOnTick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.endOnTick) and to 0 [minPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minPadding) you will get axis that starts on first date and shows tick at the end, but last date might not be displayed as a label on axis - http://jsfiddle.net/k5ckfh76/3/ Using [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) gives full control of tick placement - http://jsfiddle.net/athkombk/